# Modal breaking the layout after clicked button, dash plotly

Tags: python, layout, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm trying to apply a bootstrap modal to some buttons that are inside elements.

my problem is, when i clicked the button and show the modal. My layout page (figure) is breaking the layout.

Before click :
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV8Je.png)

After click :
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5CRi.png)

This is specific code in modal part :
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWFuV.png)

Can anyone suggest an effective solution for this case? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the modal outside of the cardbody. The way you have it is that you have placed the modal between the button and figure and so when you trigger the modal to open, it might be breaking the layout. Try placing the modal in a separate div outside of the card body (either top or bottom) and see if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, what fixed it was forcing the width of the columns that contain the graphs.

Before:

```
[dbc.Col(summary_card, width = 2),
 dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="summary1")),
 dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="summary2"))]
```

After:

```
[dbc.Col(summary_card, width = 2),
 dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="summary1"), width = 5),
 dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="summary2"), width = 5)]
```